# Google Maps API V3 undefined geocoder error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I have what is essentially a customised "venue locator", designed for a mobile site. It's very much a work in progress, but has been functioning absolutely perfectly (for well over a month) until today. Now when I click on my search button I'm getting an undefined error where I've declare the geocoder:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

I've made a few changes to the external css and js today, but no changes to the js in the document itself. I did make a few changes to the html markup but surely nothing that could be causing this error.

I've tried writing an initialise function to be called once the page is loaded, and including my map creation and geocoder declaration within that - as I've read that this problem often occurs when the maps API hasn't loaded fully - but it hasn't worked thus far; in fact, I've tried everything I've been able to find in other threads here and in other forums, also to no avail. Occasionally while I was troubleshooting I'd get errors thrown up from the Google Maps main.js file too.

I don't understand how I could have had zero errors for the past month and now, suddenly, this. If anyone can be bothered taking a look, the page is at http://www.quizmeisters.com.au/mobile-test/find.html

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a map in the link you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few things to note:

- rollback your code to the previous version and check if it works. then start making changes one at a time (change -> check; change -> check).
- there is no map in your link. you search for a `div` with `id` = `map`, but i couldn't find this element in your code.
- the script in the head is probably being executed before your page is ready.

Comment: Yeah, wow. Thanks for pointing that out, @RASG (and @Marcelo). I have no idea what happened to my map div! Must have been accidentally deleted somehow. Simply reinserting it didn't do the trick, so I went back through my files and rebuilt the page a piece at a time using bits from various backups. It's working fine now. I still got a few strange errors from the Google Maps main.js here and there, but this issue magically resolved itself once I moved from 3G to a faster wireless connection.